# Function to reverse the order in a sentence

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
text = str(input('Input sentence, please: '))

def reverse(text):
    r_text = ''
    index = len(text) - 1

    while index >= 0:
        r_text += text[index]
        index -= 1

    return r_text

print(reverse(text))
```

But the output is for example: Whats up -> pu stahW and I need it to be ->up Whats

In other words:

> Write the pseudocode and code for a function that reverses the words in a sentence.
>
> **Input**:
>
> ```
> "This is awesome"
> ```
>
> **Output**:
>
> ```
> "awesome is This".
> ```
>
> Give the Big O notation.

Answer (score 4):

```
def reverse_order(sentence):
    return ' '.join(sentence.split(' ')[::-1])
```

Comment: I believe the argument to `split` is redundant. (`.split()` suffices)

Comment: @Alec Well, not exactly. Without argument, it splits on any white space not just spaces. However, I'm not sure which one is best here.

Answer (score 1):

`split` should work. That chunks it by whitespace. Then reverse the array. Finally join the reversed array on ' '

```
a = "What's up"

bits = a.split()
print(bits)   # yields: ["What's", 'up']

bits_reversed = bits[::-1]
print(bits_reversed)  # yields: ['up', "What's"]

print(' '.join(bits_reversed))
```

Comment: I get a strange output:
`["What's", 'up']
['up', "What's"]
up What's
`

Comment: Join the array on `' '`   See the edit

Comment: @ErikTonev That's because there are three print statements to show what the answer is doing.

Comment: Yeah lol, I removed 2 of them but yeah, it does the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>>> " ".join("Hello world".split()[::-1])
'world Hello'
```

or, if you want it in a function:

```
>>> def reverse(text):
...     return " ".join(text.split()[::-1])
...
>>> reverse("Hello world")
'world Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reverse()` function for `list`:

```
s = "What's up"
l1 = s.split()
l1.reverse()
res = ' '.join(l1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
"up What's"
```

In a custom function:

```
def reverse_sentence(s):
    l = s.split()
    l.reverse()
    return ' '.join(l)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> reverse_sentence("What's up")
"up What's"
```